# Data is not passing through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

I want to send the integer value from one activity to another but I am not getting the value,There is no error in my project.If I am giving the static value it is working so problem with intent only..

Passing the data

```
try {
                                JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(doc);
                                final  String statusCode=jsonobject.get("code").toString();
                                System.out.print("Code......>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+statusCode);
                                switch (statusCode){

                                    case "400":
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + doc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;

                                    case "200":

                                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SecondActivity.this);
                                        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.link_dialog);

                                        Button dialogButtonCustomercare = (Button) dialog
                                                .findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
                                        Button dialogButtonCustomer = (Button) dialog
                                                .findViewById(R.id.button_contact_us);

                                        dialogButtonCustomercare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                                                i.putExtra("StatusCode", 200);
                                                startActivity(i);

                                               // dialog.dismiss();


                                            }
                                        });
                                        dialogButtonCustomer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                makeCall(phonenumber);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        dialog.show();


                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops something went wrong! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.i("Error", e.getMessage());
                            }
```

Getting the data

int responseCode  ;

```
 Intent i = getIntent();

        responseCode = i.getIntExtra("StatusCode",0);
 System.out.print("Status Code" + responseCode);
   if (responseCode==200) {
            DetailsImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // textview.settext(bank details verification done)

        } else {
            DetailImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: try like extras.'responseCode  = extras.getInt("StatusCode");'

Comment: are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: @Aiyaz Parmar  not now but before this i was trying to send string that time null object reference .

Comment: What is the value you are getting? intent seems okay... try debugging it if the  bundle has extras.

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu i am trying to debug only blank screen is coming

Comment: I mean to say set breakpoints on your startActivity(i) ,getintent and check in your Studio/Eclipse

Comment: I resolved the issue, after doing finish();  after passing the data

Answer (score 3):

```
dialogButtonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("StatusCode", 200);

        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sucessful intent" +200, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```